# Mathematica 8: EdgeList and CommunityStructureAssignment shadowing problem

Tags: graphs-and-networks, packages, partitions

I'm facing some issues when trying to use the `CommunityStructureAssignment` function from the GraphUtilities package in Mathematica 8.

I'd like to output a community structure assignment for my random graph, but it seems the function is unrecognized by Mathematica.
In particular with the following code I'm creating a random weighted graph `G` with 10 nodes and 30 edges and I visualize the weighted adjacency matrix:

```
nNodes = 10;
nEdges = 30;
G = Graph[EdgeList[RandomGraph[{nNodes, nEdges}]], EdgeWeight -> RandomReal[{0.1, 5}, nEdges]];

W = WeightedAdjacencyMatrix[G];
W // MatrixForm
```

After that, following the documentation of `CommunityStructureAssignment`, I'd imagine that feeding the `EdgeList` of `G` directly to `CommunityStructureAssignment` would result in a list but:

```
CommunityStructureAssignment[EdgeList[G], Weighted -> True]
```

returns it self:

```
CommunityStructureAssignment[{1 \[UndirectedEdge] 4, 
  1 \[UndirectedEdge] 5, 2 \[UndirectedEdge] 4, 2 \[UndirectedEdge] 5,
   2 \[UndirectedEdge] 1, 2 \[UndirectedEdge] 3, 
  3 \[UndirectedEdge] 5, 3 \[UndirectedEdge] 1, 4 \[UndirectedEdge] 5,
   4 \[UndirectedEdge] 3}, Weighted -> True]
```

while the documentation clearly says that:

```
g = {3 -> 2, 2 -> 1, 1 -> 3, 3 -> 5, 5 -> 6, 6 -> 7, 7 -> 5};
CommunityStructureAssignment[g]
```

should correctly work.

Now the question is: how can I feed the correct input graph into CommunityStructureAssignment? And also how to include the edge weights into the `EdgeList`?

Also I have to say, that once i import the GraphUtilities package, the definition of `EdgeList` turns red. Is this because there is a conflict of names?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am using *Mathematica* 10 but I suppose the same issues will apply.  I believe that the GraphUtilites package is not designed to work with `Graph` objects but instead other, earlier formats.

After loading `` Needs["GraphUtilities`"] `` the Symbol `EdgeList` is highlighted in red indicating shadowing, meaning that this Symbol exists in multiple contexts in the [`$ContextPath`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/$ContextPath.html).  If the one from the package context is used it does not recognize `G`:

```
GraphUtilities`EdgeList[G]
```

[image]

Likewise it seems that `CommunityStructureAssignment` does not recognize `\[UndirectedEdge]` as it was presumably written before the introduction of that functionality.  If we use the `` System` `` `EdgeList` function and replace `UndirectedEdge` with `Rule`:

```
CommunityStructureAssignment[Rule @@@ System`EdgeList[G], Weighted -> True]
```

> ```
> {1, 2, 3, 4, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2}
> ```

Comment: That's magic! It works, thanks, you saved my day!